# How to convert and export a list of xlsx files to csv files in R

Tags: r, csv, export-to-csv, lapply, xlsx

I'm attempting to convert a large number of .xlsx files to .csv, while also specifying a new folder or directory for them to be placed in. Specifically, I want to create a new folder in my working directory to house the newly-converted .csv files.

Based on previous examples, I have managed to complete the conversion portion using the following code

```
setwd("~/Myfolder")

files.to.read = list.files(pattern="xlsx")

lapply(files.to.read, function(f) {  
df = read.xlsx(f, sheetIndex=1)  
write.csv(df, gsub("xlsx", "csv", f), row.names=FALSE)})
```

This successfully converts all .xlsx files to .csv in my original working directory. However, what I want is to create a new subfolder within that directory and place those .csv files in it. I know the answer likely involves adding either 
`dir.create()`
or 
`file.path()` to the `write.csv()` command. However, when I use either of them, I get the following error.

`Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : invalid 'open' argument`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know without a reproducible example. What happens if you try to do `read.xlsx(files.to.read[1], sheetIndex=1)`?

If that works, you are quite close.

```
dir.create("your_folder_name")

files.to.read = list.files(pattern="xlsx")

lapply(files.to.read, function(f) {  
df = read.xlsx(f, sheetIndex=1)
# Make the new filename here
new_filename = file.path(getwd(), "your_folder_name", gsub("xlsx", "csv", f))  
write.csv(df, new_filename , row.names=FALSE)
# provide some feedback
print(paste("Writing", new_filename))
}
)
```

It might be that your `list.files()` command is having trouble. 
If the previous fails, Try:

```
# Mind the full.names=TRUE to get the full path
files.to.read = list.files(pattern="xlsx", full.names=TRUE)
```

And get rid of the `new_filename` line. You won't need to create it via `file.path`, just use the `gsub` command as you were doing.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. Do you have any ideas on how to improve the computing speed of the function? Perhaps an alternative to `read.xlsx` ?

Comment: That's a broad question...It might work faster if you use `readxl::read_xlsx()` and specify the column types (so that the function does not waste time on guessing). I don't know the type of files you are trying to read and how *fast* you need it to go. What timescale are we talking about?